# Visual Studio 2019 changes to package.json no longer trigger update

Tags: visual-studio

Some time after upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 16.[something].[something] changes to the package.json file no longer triggered the automatic update/download of the changed packages to the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set "Restore On Save" to True (Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > Package Restore.

The setting must have been set to False during one of the VS2019 updates.

[image]